# How do I find the function pointers for tests from the LLVM IR code of a Rust program?

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-ir

We are developing a [mutation testing system based on LLVM](https://github.com/mull-project/mull). The system supports C++ projects that use GoogleTest and I am trying to support Rust. To do so, we need to accomplish the following steps:

1. Compile the language into LLVM IR. Rust supports this.
2. Find the tests in the LLVM IR.
3. Run the tests the code that is exercised by the tests ("testees").

The challenge is to find the unit test methods via LLVM IR API.

Consider [the following example](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/54d0e6f4ddea458a5d77fa707b26acef9f5a6093/lab/rust/example.rs). It has 4 tests and one testee function:

```
pub fn sum(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    return a + b;
}

pub fn just_print() {
    println!("I am just_print() function. I just say hello!");
}

#[test]
fn rusttest_foo_sum1() {
    assert!(sum(3, 4) == 7);
}

#[test]
fn rusttest_foo_sum2() {
    assert!(sum(4, 5) == 9);
}

#[test]
fn rusttest_foo_sum3() {
    assert!(sum(5, 6) == 11);
}

#[test]
fn rusttest_foo_sum4() {
    assert!(sum(5, 6) == 11);
}
```

This is [the slightly prettified LLVM IR](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/54d0e6f4ddea458a5d77fa707b26acef9f5a6093/lab/rust/example.ll.pretty) that is produced when compiling this Rust code.

Having explored that LLVM IR for a while, one can notice that Rust/Cargo run tests via a function `main` that invokes the `test_main_static` function which is given arrays of descriptions. Each description is a pair of a test function name and a test function pointer. [See the `@ref.e` at line 47](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/b5b9bdf1d3c8c876b45c3096006a4dd4dfba4493/lab/rust/example.ll.pretty#L47).

Our challenge is to collect function pointers to these tests by parsing this sophisticated struct layout so that later we can run these functions via LLVM JIT by giving it the function pointers we accumulated.

The obvious brute-force approach we are going to take is to run through this struct layout and parse the structs carefully and find the correct offsets of the test functions. This approach appears to be not portable across different versions of Rust or LLVM IR that might change in a future.

What is the easiest and at the same time reliable way of finding the test function pointers, other than the default of parsing the offsets by hand?

This question has been also [cross-posted to the Rust forums](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/need-help-in-parsing-llvm-ir-code-generated-by-a-rust-program-having-unit-tests/9407).

Comment: I am not sure how you'll manage to do it, but I certainly wish you luck. Having mutation testing in Rust would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [made it work](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/pull/109) by using the brute-force approach that I outlined in my question. Using the LLVM C++ API, we:

- find a pointer to `test_main_static`
- find the reference to `@ref.e` in `test_main_static`
- enumerate through `@ref.e` structure and find the test function pointers

The approach seems to work but our concern is still that it might be not portable across different versions of Rust/LLVM. One of our next steps will be to implement checks of integrity of the LLVM IR produced by `rustc --test`. Another step will be to try this `RustTestFinder` on real code bases and see if we have any problems.

I would still appreciate any information about LLVM IR produced by `rustc --test` that could make things more straightforward.